# IdleConnectionHandler removing a connection that never existed in my android app

Tags: android, android-networking

My android app keeps logging this warning :

```
IdleConnectionHandler removing a connection that never existed
```

What does that mean? Is that a big problem? What should I do to avoid this?
My app makes many http connections in AsyncTask, is that related?

EDIT:

I found that this call was the reason of this message :

```
httpclient.getConnectionManager().closeIdleConnections(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

So maybe it tries to close some connections that don't exist?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like there is a logic error in your code. You may be able to track down the problems using this Android tool called ARO. You can find out more about it here http://developer.att.com/developer/legalAgreementPage.jsp?passedItemId=9700312
It will help you to understand more about how your application is using the network and how you can improve that part of your application to make it more efficient.
Is there a reason you need to make many http connections at once?

Answer (score 0):

I got that error too, but my app uses internet only for ad loading. Currently I have no permission that my app can use internet, so that is why it says "Removing a connection that never existed". That may be one of the reason for this warning.